# Add perpendicular arrows to lines in ArcGIS Pro Symbology

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, direction

I want to add arrows to lines, which indicate the direction where you should look at the line from (the lines are excavation profile). I want to do that using an attribute which indicates the direction (north, south etc). My problem is that if I do this, the arrows do not point in the same direction even they are symbolized using the same attribute and symbology settings.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in ArcGIS Pro:

1. Create your two start and end rotation fields for each line
2. Edit symbology and add a shape marker to the **end** of the line, set it to be an arrow, apply any offset and make sure marker placement is at the end.
3. Add a shape marker to the **start** of the line, set it to be an arrow, apply any offset and make sure marker placement is at the start.
4. In the 3 line menu (at top of symbology panel) set allow symbol property connection.
5. A tiny drum icon with a + sign appears next to many of the properties of the symbol, set the start marker to be your start field and your end marker to be your end field.

If you are unfamiliar with symbol editing here is a screenshot highlighting some of the steps I outline above.

[image: Screenshot]